# Sequilize Mysql Foreign Key is null

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

These are my models

Files

```
exports.models = File = sequelize.define("File", {
  originalname: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  destination: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  filename: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  path: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
```

Sales

```
exports.models = Sales = sequelize.define("sales", {
  OrderDate: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  Region: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  City: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  Category: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  Product: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  Quantity: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  UnitPrice: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  TotalPrice: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
```

and now I add the relation

```
  await File.hasMany(Sales);
  await Sales.belongsTo(File);

  await sequelize
    .sync({ force: true })
    .then(async () => {
      console.log("Database & tables created!");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err);
    });
});
```

now with the sync method
the ORM Creates my Tables with all the columns that I have defined and additionally, it will create an id column in both the Sales and Files Tables automatically along with a FileID column in the Sales table as a foreign key
And Now

```
try {
    await File.create(req.file);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "Server Error File NOt Uploaded To Database" });
    return;
  }

  try {
    await Sales.bulkCreate(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "Internal Server Error Data canot be uploaded" });
    return;
  }
```

when I try to insert data into my Database all the data is inserted correctly except for the foreign key which is null
I tried putting the NOT Null Constrain in there but after I do that the database returns an error which basically says that this table can not have this constrain
to my knowledge I have tried everything under sun and I really need help
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show what's in `data`?

Comment: ```[ {
        "OrderDate": "1/1/20",
        "Region": "East",
        "City": "Boston",
        "Category": "Bars",
        "Product": "Carrot",
        "Quantity": "33",
        "UnitPrice": "1.77",
        "TotalPrice": "58.41"
    },
    {
        "OrderDate": "1/4/20",
        "Region": "East",
        "City": "Boston",
        "Category": "Crackers",
        "Product": "Whole Wheat",
        "Quantity": "87",
        "UnitPrice": "3.49",
        "TotalPrice": "303.63"
    },]``` it is an array of json objects

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see `FileId` props in `data`

Comment: I don't understand how am I suppose to pass the FileId Props